# Viewing runtime exception message from java program

Tags: java, runtime-error, filewriter

while running a sort program for some custom data, I got some runtime exception which took up the whole console in eclipse. I would like to see the cause and the message of the exception.So I used a  FileWriter as below to write the exception message. However the textfile is of 0 bytes, meaning nothing is written.

I also tried to run the code from the terminal(in linux -ubuntu) and using > to redirect the exception message ,but only got the output from system.out.println()
The FileWriter doesn't write the exception message.

Below is the relevant part of code.. Can someone tell me why this happened? I tried adding fw.flush() but it didn't make any difference.

```
public class MySort{
    ...
    public static void sort(String[] data){
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] a = {"E","A","S","Y","Q","U","E","S","T","I","O","N"};
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("sorterr.txt");
        try{
        sort(a);
         }catch(RuntimeException e){
            System.out.println("some text");
            fw.write(e.getMessage());
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }  
   }
}
```

When run in Eclipse or Linux terminal, `sorterr.txt` is `0` bytes

In terminal, redirect also behaves the same. In short nothing inside the catch block prints out the values.

UPDATE:
It was a stackoverflow error ,that was the reason why it wasn't caught by the catch block (which was meant for RuntimeException)..

I detected this by setting

`System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("error.txt")));`

thus,the stacktrace was printed in error.txt and this showed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at mysort.exercises.MySort.partition(MySort.java:67)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
File file = new File("sorterr.txt");
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
output.write(e.getMessage());
output.close();
```

The problem is that you are using FileWriter wrong.

Comment: tried that..still the same result.. all error stacktrace printed to stdout and not to the file